# Reading in CCB file in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Just a quick question here that i'm having trouble with.

Does anyone know of a way to read in CCB files using CCBReader without adding the images from the CCB file into the texture cache?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, and it's not even something specific to CCBReader. Any image that is loaded in cocos2d through any means, be it creating a texture from image, a sprite frame or a sprite from file, or a bitmap font, gets added to the texture cache. The same way that any use of an image or sprite frame first checks the cache whether that particular image or texture atlas is already loaded.

What you can do is to purge specific textures from the cache, or the entire cache altogether. This will not necessarily remove the textures from memory, however. As long as a texture is still in use, say by a sprite, that texture will remain in memory. But it's memory will be released when the last sprite using that texture deallocates if the texture itself isn't in the texture cache.

However, as soon as you create another sprite using the same texture the image first needs to be loaded as a texture again, which is a slow process. It will also cache the texture again because that's what the cache is for: to prevent having to go through the slow loading process again.

In case you were asking because you have memory pressure related issues, there's nothing you can do except reduce the amount of memory your textures are using. Either by using fewer textures, or reducing their quality (ie reduce color depth) or use the PVR format to be able to use in-memory compressed textures.

Comment: yeah i'm currently removing specific textures at certain times. do you know a way of using pvr images in cocosbuilder?